# AfterEffects Script giving error on Opacity

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I'm have a simple script to turn off the Source.Text when the counter reaches 0

```
rate = -1;
clockStart = 10;
clockTime = Math.max((clockStart-1*(time-inPoint)),0);

if (clockTime ==0)
{
thisComp.layer("Counter").transform.opacity.setValue(0);
clockTime
}
```

`Counter` is the layer whose sourcetext I need to put the Opacity as 0. The script is functioning fine. But in the comp window it displays an error: `The project contains an expression error`. The line it mentions is pointing to the following code:

`thisComp.layer("Counter").transform.opacity.setValue(0);`

Whats wrong with this line? It's effective despite the error.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use extendscript for an expression. The two are different things. If you want to run this as a script you have to run it through the file>script> menu, not in the expression editor of the property.

The expressions language doesn't have the `setValue()` function. The expression just has to return a value and that will be the value of the property the expression is applied to. If you want to change the value of another property you have to apply another expression to it. Or you can set the value with a script, which acts just like you set it yourself with the gui.